# Perl Anyevent , non blocking redis push

Tags: perl, event-handling, anyevent

I have the code below to do non blocking rpush into a redis server
When I run this for just 1 rpush , the code works fine 
But when I run this in a while loop the script hangs after the first execution. 
Why ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                          
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Redis::RipeRedis;
use strict;
#my $cv = AE::cv();                                                                                                                                                      

my $redis = AnyEvent::Redis::RipeRedis->new(
  host     => 'localhost',
  port     => '6379',
    );

my $i=0;

my $cv;
while($i++ < 5) {
    $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
    $redis->rpush( 'list', "1","2","3",
                   { on_done => sub {
                   my $data = shift;
                   print "$data\n";
                     },
                   }
        );
    $cv->recv();
}
$redis->quit(
    sub {$cv->send();}
    );
$cv->recv();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You block script execution  when you call $cv->recv() in while loop and script are waiting $cv->send or $cv->croak, but in callback you don't call $cv->send().

> $cv->recv
>
> Wait (blocking if necessary) until the ->send or ->croak methods have been called on $cv, while servicing other watchers normally.

If you want to send different not blocking requestes try to use AnyEvents begin and end methods.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Redis::RipeRedis;
use strict;

my $redis = AnyEvent::Redis::RipeRedis->new(
  host     => 'localhost',
  port     => '6379',
);

my $i=0;

my  $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
while($i++ < 5) {
   $cv->begin;
   $redis->rpush( 'list', "1","2","3",
               { 
                  on_done => sub {
                    my $data = shift;
                    print "$data\n";
                    $cv->end();
                  },
               }
    );
}

$cv->recv();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you haven't defined, connection_timeout:

```
my $redis = AnyEvent::Redis::RipeRedis->new(
  host     => 'localhost',
  port     => '6379',
    );
```

Should looks like:

```
  my $redis = AnyEvent::Redis::RipeRedis->new(
    host => 'localhost',
    port => '6379',
    password => 'your_password',
    connection_timeout => 5,
    reconnect => 1,
    encoding => 'utf8');
```

From:

ftp://ftp.uni-siegen.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/I/IP/IPH/AnyEvent-Redis-RipeRedis-1.002.readme